# Replace character after file name string variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string like the following in bash:

```
string=P001_WA05_1_i5-_i7-SI_GA_A5_1_S1_*_
```

I want to replace the `_[0-9]_` after `W[[:alpha:]]+([0-9])` with an asterisk and the `[0-9]_[[:alpha:]][0-9]` after `SI_GA_[[:alpha:]]+([0-9])` with a asterisk.

The desired output for this string is `P001_WA05*i5-_i7-SI_GA_A5_*_*_`

How can this be done? I included the above formats in regex, but I am unsure how to replace the indicated values after the indicated patterns with an asterisk.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: The `$string` seems not to match with the pattern `WA[[:alpha:]]+([0-9])` because "WA" is not followed by alphabetic character(s) in your string.

Comment: @tshiono Sorry, corrected - it should be W[[:alpha:]]...

Comment: Hmm.. it should be `W[[:alpha:]][0-9]+` right?

Comment: @tshiono That might be correct I am not too good with the regexes. What I meant is W[[:alpha:]]+([0-9]) but maybe W[[:alpha:]][0-9]+ is correct. Essentially I want W plus a single alpha char and multiple digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the matched pattern(s) surrounded by parens via `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` etc. as a back reference. Then you can say something like:

```
string=P001_WA05_1_i5-_i7-SI_GA_A5_1_S1_*_
if [[ $string =~ (.*W[[:alpha:]][0-9]+)_[0-9]_(.*SI_GA_[[:alpha:]]+[0-9]_)[0-9]_[[:alpha:]][0-9](.*)  ]]; then
    string="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}*${BASH_REMATCH[2]}*${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
echo "$string"
```

The 1st sub-pattern `.*W[[:alpha:]][0-9]+` matches with `P001_WA05`, the 2nd one `.*SI_GA_[[:alpha:]]+[0-9]_` with `SI_GA_A5_` and so on.
Then you can concatenate these sub-strings along with your replacements: "`*`".
Hope this helps.